# How does Rebuild in host-raid RAID-1 works?

Tags: raid1

I am testing a **Non-Hardware Raid** with 3 1TB Disks.
I create a RAID-1 Array with my first 2 Disks and installed Windows 7 on the Raid disk that i'd created. I unplugged the first disk SATA cable in RAID Array and reboot the system. When i entered the RAID Controller by pressing "Ctrl+I" I get the message which asked me to add the free disk to the array. after i add that disk The Raid Volume status changed to Rebuild. under the Screen there is a yellow message : "**Volumes with Rebuild status will be rebuilt within the operating system**".

*Here are my questions:*

1. What does it mean by that message ? does it mean that i just need to boot into my windows and all the Rebuild happens automatically or do I need any kind of software ?
2. How can i monitor how much the Rebuilding process is completed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an Intel Rapid Storage RAID controller. This is **not** hardware RAID. Like most onboard/motherboard RAID controllers it is **host-RAID**.

"Volumes with Rebuild status will be rebuilt within the operating system" means exactly that, Rapid Storage relies on a driver within the OS to perform it's work. It is incapable of doing any actual RAID'ing by itself.

Status will be shown using the Intel Rapid Storage console which normally comes  bundled with the RAID driver. You're also better off adding/removing/replacing disks using the Windows software and not the very limited BIOS interface.

Comment: Sorry to revive this old thread but it's the closes answer to my problem also.. rergarding "Volumes with Rebuild status will be rebuilt within the operating system" - my OS installation is on the disks in state "Rebuild", both of which are Raid 1 (mirror)...  any thoughts how I get into te OS? is there a boot tool that will let me that rebuild proceed without OS ?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your RAID controller the rebuilding should happen as long as you have the machine turned on, but you may need to boot to Windows.

Hardware RAID cards will rebuild automatically, no need to do anything, you don't even need an OS. Many consumer motherboards (Intel Raid etc) it's not real hardware RAID, you may need to boot Windows for the drivers to continue the rebuild (I'm not 100% certain here).

What RAID controller do you have, they usually have their own software that can be used for management/viewing the rebuild process.

I have used various RAID systems (LSI, Intel, Highpoint) and I have never come across one that needs you to do anything to rebuild. Usually just hitting that rebuild option is enough.

Comment: Thanks benpix
I don't know if it is fake or real. I entered it with Ctrl+I and it mentioned "Intel Rapid Storage ...". It seems that it doesn't do the Rebuild operation when you are in the Raid Console, but when you are in windows, it does the Rebuilding process.

Comment: Intel Rapid Storage is indeed "fake"/"hybrid" raid, nice to know it requires OS to rebuild. Have you downloaded the "Matrix Storage Console"? It will show you rebuild progress in Windows.